# How to check whether the cell has a subview or not in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cell, subview

I am new to iPhone development. I have a view called barView which is added as the subview to the cell, I want to check for the condition like this

```
if(cell has a subview barview)
{
do something.......
}else 
{
do something......
}
```

How can I check like this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way is to give your `barview` a special tag:

```
barview.tag = 123221;
```

and then check with

```
UIView* barview = [cell viewWithTag:123221];
if (barview != nil) {
  ...
}
```

---

Otherwise, you need to iterate through the `.subviews` array and check if the property matches, e.g.

```
UIView* barview = nil;
for (UIView* subview in cell.subviews) {
   if ([subview isKindOfClass:[BarView class]]) {
      barview = subview;
      break;
   }
}
if (barview != nil) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (barView.superview == cell)
{
   …
```